# In rails automated testing how do I spawn the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm writing some automated tests for an app using rails 3.1. One of my tests is failing and at the point of failure I want to be able to jump into the rails console and inspect the state of things. Leading up to this assertion a lot of objects were created and states were changed.

After the test suite finishes running the test database is cleared.

I remember there was some way to insert a breakpoint in the test file or something similar which would throw me into the console. I've done a ton of googling and can't find it.

Anyone?

Comment: I should add that I don't simply mean "rails console test", I know how to do that. I specifically want to inspect the state at the point my assertion is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Require ruby-debug on your Gemfile.

If on 1.8:

`gem 'ruby-debug'`

If on 1.9:

`gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'`

Note that if you're on 1.9.3 requires a [few tweaks](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug).

Finally, put a `debugger` statement where you want to debug, and run your tests. It should popup a console.

I'd also recommend taking a look at [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), as Amadan stated.

Comment: Ugh, I'm new to stackoverflow and just discovered comments don't allow newlines. I edited my question with the issue I'm still having. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the `debugger` before the assert.

Comment: "debugger" is before the assert. Just to make sure I'm not crazy I moved it up a few more lines but it still isn't firing.

Comment: I have a new clue. I put "debugger" into a control and hit the web server. The logs gave me an error that "Debugger requested, but was not available (ensure ruby-debug is listed in Gemfile...". I have 'ruby-debug19' listed for sure. I tried changing to 'ruby-debug' but then I get an error about incompatible ruby version.

Comment: Try: `ruby -Itest test/integration/trading_system_sequence_test.rb`

Comment: For running a Rails Server with debug, you need to run using `rails server --debug` or, for a shorter version, `rails s -u`.

Comment: I finally figured it out, thanks for sticking with me. :) The line in the Gemfile needs to be: gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => "ruby-debug"  But then I had another issue with ruby 1.9.3 which was solved by: http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug

Comment: I've updated the answer with your info. Sorry for the ruby-debug thing. :)

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for your help. You definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use Pry, and say `binding.pry` as a breakpoint.

You might like [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails).

Comment: Amanda's suggestion is brief, but don't overlook it. I use pry all the time and I consider it easier than ruby-debug. The linked rails cast is a good way to start.